# Messaging over Stellar - Is that right to do?

Tags: javascript-sdk, multi-sig, dataentry

```
/*
 * Hi!
 * 
 * I'm sending this tiny library for you to check. This is the basis of the
 * on-chain signature collection solution I'm writing. It includes collecting
 * signatures for multi-signatures accounts as well as sharing transactions XDR
 * between signers.
 * 
 * The present module implement a messaging system to cut and send those datas
 * to the blockchain. It takes advantage of the fact that one can set the value
 * of the same data entry up to 100 times in one transaction. Actually, 99 as
 * the first operation is a payment of 0.0000001XLM to the destination address.
 * 
 * The signature/transaction sharing solution will makes use of dedicated
 * addresses where to send/collect those datas.
 * 
 * The reason I'm sending this to you is that the same messaging system could be
 * used to "abuse" the network. Well, actually you're the one to say if it would
 * be an abuse or not. And I'd like to know about that.
 * 
 * Using this library, one can send up to 6KB to the blockchain for a cost of
 * 100 stroops. This could open very interesting possibilities, like mailing
 * over Stellar, on-chain twitter-like services and even some basic blogging
 * capabilities as gzip would allow to emit articles up to 16KB.
 * 
 * I know you keep your archive light, so this may be a bit disruptive or
 * incompatible with your current goals for Stellar.
 * 
 * Just for you to know, I'm not the only one who found about this and some
 * people mentionned it indirectly on Galactic Talk. Umbrel implemented it in
 * a transaction-passing solution for papaya bot a few days ago. So this
 * possibility is not going to stay secret anyway.
 * 
 * I've been thinking about how to prevent abuse of this features and I didn't
 * found solution, really. It could be made that one have to use 99 different
 * data entry instead, but it would burden the account with cryptic labels
 * and the additionnal cost would be payed only once - it wouldn't do.
 * 
 * We could fix a maximum of 10 manageData operation or so per transaction.
 * But it would only make it a bit harder to code the exact same thing.
 * 
 * We could raise the fee for this kind of transaction, but it would make
 * multi-sig collection expansive which may not be desirable at all.
 * 
 * Another solution that would cut the possibility of on-chain signature
 * collection would be to forbid mixing manageData operations with other kind
 * of operations. But of course it would forbid a lot of precious innovations
 * as well.
 * 
 * So I would recommend to let it happen and see how much GB it's going to grow.
 * Eventually the message-passing transactions could be recognized as such and
 * deleted after a delay of a year or so, to prevent the archive to grow too
 * big. I assume that the cost of the GB of storage is low enough for that to
 * works.
 * 
 * Well anyway it's only the conclusion I came to. I assume to are in a better
 * position than me to say what we should do with that. And if you're open to it
 * I'd be glad to code some mailing over Stellar demonstrating the possibilities
 * of the network.
 * 
 * I really wonder if you did expect this kind of things when calling
 * developpers to innovate and surprise you with new uses of your blockchain?
 * 
 * Antoine alias Mister.Ticot
 */


(function (root, f) {
  'use_strict'
  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) module.exports = f(root)
  else root.messenger = f(root)
}(this, function(root) {
  'use_strict'
  if (typeof require !== 'undefined') var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk')
  else StellarSdk = root.StellarSdk

  /// Get Buffer constructor from StellarSdk
  var memo = new StellarSdk.Memo('hash', '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
  var Buffer = memo.value.__proto__.constructor

  var messenger = {}

  /**
   * Build a transaction to be signed by `senderAccount` to send `message` to
   * `destination`, with `object` as memo. The maximum size for `message` is
   * 6336 bytes.
   * 
   * The cost of emission is 1 stroop + 1 stroop for each 64 bytes to send.
   * 
   * @param {AccountResponse} senderAccount The Account object as return by `StellarSdk.Server.loadAccount()`
   * @param {String} destination The publicKey where to send the message
   * @param {String} object The memo of the transaction (max. 28 bytes)
   * @param {String} message The message to be send
   * @return {Transaction} A StellarSdk Transaction object
   */
  messenger.send = function (senderAccount, destination, object, message) {
    var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(senderAccount)
    if (object.length > 28) console.log('Warning: object will be truncated.')
    transaction.addMemo(new StellarSdk.Memo('text', object.substr(0,28)))
    transaction.addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
      destination: destination,
      asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
      amount: '0.0000001'
    }))
    var array = new Buffer(message)
    if (array.length > 99*64) console.log('Warning: message will be truncated.')
    for (let i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
      const chunk = array.slice(i*64, i*64+64)
      if (chunk.length === 0) break
      transaction.addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.manageData({
        name: 'Send',
        value: chunk
      }))
    }
    return transaction.build()
  }

  /**
   * Return the message object from `txHash`, using `server` to fetch datas.
   * 
   * @param {Server} server A StellarSdk Server object
   * @param {String} txHash A transaction hash
   * @return {Object} A message object with `sender`, `object`, `date` and
   *     `message` fields.
   */
  messenger.read = function(server, txHash) {
    var caller = server.transactions()
    return caller.transaction(txHash).call()
      .then(function(answer) {
        return { 
          sender: answer.source_account,
          object: answer.memo, 
          date: answer.created_at,
          message: extractMessage(answer)
        }
      })
  }

  function extractMessage (txCallAnswer) {
    if (txCallAnswer.operation_count < 2) return null
    var array = []
    var tx = new StellarSdk.Transaction(txCallAnswer.envelope_xdr)
    tx.operations.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.type === 'manageData' && entry.name === 'Send') {
        console.log(entry.value)
        array.push(entry.value)
      }
    })
    return Buffer.concat(array).toString()
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the SDF, but since you are asking about this, you probably already have guessed that this is not intended functionality. As such, I wouldn't rely on this behavior being there forever for any particular product you're developing. I would expect this to be addressed if it ever became a widespread problem.